# Hive equivalent of sql update

Tags: hive

I am trying to convert below query equivalent to hive.

updating tier_cd in rpt table but hive 0.13  doesn't support update so using the changing to hive equivalent and output is not correct.

```
UPDATE test_report A 
SET TIER_CD = (SELECT B.TIER_CD FROM lk  B
WHERE B.CLASS_CD = A.CLASS_CD AND B.RC_TYPE_CD = 'OATS' 
AND A.ACPTD_ROE_CT >= B.BEGIN_QT 
AND A.ACPTD_ROE_CT <= B.END_QT
AND EFCTV_DT = (SELECT MAX(C.EFCTV_DT) FROM LK C WHERE 
C.CLASS_CD = B.CLASS_CD AND C.RC_TYPE_CD = 'OATS' AND 
C.TIER_CD = B.TIER_CD AND
C.EFCTV_DT <= ?
AND B.TIER_CD <> 'I')
WHERE A.YEAR_CD = ?
AND A.MONTH_CD = ?;
```

HIve equivalent is below

```
select z.*,x.tier_Cd from
(
select * from test_report
where year_Cd=?
and month_Cd=?')z
left outer join
(SELECT B.TIER_CD TIER_cD, A.MKT_CLASS_CD,A.year_cd FROM LK B, test_report A
WHERE B.CLASS_CD = A.CLASS_CD AND B.RC_TYPE_CD = 'OATS' 
AND A.ACPTD_ROE_CT >= B.BEGIN_QT 
AND A.ACPTD_ROE_CT <= B.END_QT
AND EFCTV_DT = (SELECT MAX(C.EFCTV_DT) FROM LK C WHERE 
C.CLASS_CD = B.CLASS_CD AND C.RC_TYPE_CD = 'OATS' AND 
C.TIER_CD = B.TIER_CD AND
C.EFCTV_DT <= ?)  
AND B.TIER_CD <> 'I')x
on(z.class_Cd=x.Class_Cd)
```

please assist what's wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't support multiple subqueries instead you can connect three tables with only joins. My guess is you're getting an error near `select (max`